# showing user position in game side map

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a game and player has to reach  at specific  destination.

I want to **show side game map** to guide him the way that where is he now and where he has to go. Just like **GTA and other game** where a side map always appear in any screen corner which guide player.
I don't have any idea how can I do this I checked it on google but maybe I'm missing the appropriate words for searching.

currently I made a photo of my scene and just showing it on right bottom corner of my game screen. how can I place current user position and destination position and change it accordingly as player move??

```
public Texture mapTexture;
void OnGUI() {
   GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(Screen.width - 200, Screen.height-200, 200, 200),mapTexture);
}
```

Comment: If you mean a minimap, my first suggestion is to just parent an orthographic camera to the player and have it looking straight down at the player. Then have the camera render to the corner of the screen by modifying its viewport rect. This could save you a lot of time coding, and let you focus on just creating the directional indicator for the destination.

Comment: i m newbie please add details with answer in answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to google and  @Serlite.
using this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_M__Hwr8Zx4) and [unity3d Web](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/20676/how-do-i-create-a-minimap.html).
I made side camera (minimap camera) parent to my player and set the ***Normalized View Port Rect*** property setting and Al-hamdu-lillah its working:)!! "" [camera setting](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html)